# How to use a unique id for each menu and highlight by id rather than a class in Laravel 5.6?

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, laravel-5

working with laravel 5.6 and I have bootstrap sidemenu items, like this,

```
<li class="{{ active_menu(Route::CurrentRouteName(), 'reports', 0,7)}}">
    <a href="{{route('reports.alluser')}}">All Users</a></li>

    <li class="{{ active_menu(Route::CurrentRouteName(), 'reports', 0,7)}}">
    <a href="{{route('reports.pie_chart')}}">Category Chart</a></li>

    <li class="{{ active_menu(Route::CurrentRouteName(), 'reports', 0,7)}}">
    <a href="{{route('reports.categorystatic')}}">Category Static</a></li>
```

I have helper function for this sidemenu in app/helper/Helper.php

```
<?php

if(! function_exists('active_menu')) {
    function active_menu($currentRouteName, $requestName, $start, $finish){
        if (substr($currentRouteName,$start, $finish) == $requestName){
            return 'active';

        }else{
            return null;
        }
    }
    }
```

but when I click one menu link above highlight all menu links. problem is here in the all links, it is highlight all menu witch include 'reports', 0,7

```
'reports', 0,7
```

How can I prevent highlighting all menu items and highlighting only selected menu item? I think if I use id rather than class I can fix the problem. but I have no an idea how can I use id for above code segments.  give me some solution

Answer (score 1):

I recently created a helper function to help me deal with that exact problem, and here is what i came up with

```
function set_active($path, $keyword = '', $active = 'active')
{
    $url_path = Request::path();

    if (Request::is($path)
        || ($keyword && strpos($url_path, $keyword) !== false)) {
        return ' class="' . $active . '"';
    }

    return '';
    // return Request::is( $path . '*' ) ? ' class="' . $active . '"' :  '';
}
```

Then in the nav part of the blade template i did something like this

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li {!! set_active('/') !!}>
        <a href="/">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li {!! set_active('about-us') !!}>
        <a href="/about-us">About Us</a>
    </li>
    <li {!! set_active('job-listing', 'job') !!}>
        <a href="/job-listing">Jobs</a>
    </li>
    <li {!! set_active('employers', 'employer') !!}>
        <a href="/employers">Employers</a>
    </li>
    <li {!! set_active('contact-us') !!}>
        <a href="/contact-us">Contact Us</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

OR in your case do something like this

```
<li {!! set_active(Route::getCurrentRoute()->uri) !!}>
    <a href="{{route('reports.alluser')}}">All Users</a>
</li>
```

Hope it helps

Comment: is this use in Laravel?

Comment: @banda Yes, i used it in a laravel project

Comment: ok tell me what is the folder name and blade file name from this? <li {!! set_active('job-listing', 'job') !!}>
        <a href="/job-listing">Jobs</a>
    </li>

Comment: It's from `nav.blade.php` file which i include in my `main.blade.php` file, located in the `resources/views` folder

Comment: i mean please conside following codes !! set_active('job-listing', 'job')  among them what is **job-listing** and **job**

Comment: @banda `job-listing` is the actual url path that is meant to be searched for by the function and `job` is the keyword to search for in the url in case the url changes to something like this `job-listing/software-developer-203030` and th`{!!  !!}` is meant to prevent laravel from escaping the double quotes in the string returned

Comment: No, any help here

Comment: @banda I have edited my answer to make it look similar to yours

Comment: it is not highlighting here current menu items

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183837/discussion-between-kellymandem-and-banda).

Comment: ok now it is highlighting but now I need following link to convert as your codes,** <li class="{{ active_menu(Route::CurrentRouteName(), 'home', 0,7)}}">**

Comment: Now I have same problem. that means when I use two links then, highlighting all links again